# How can I use or condition in addFieldToFilter magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I am creating a search form where user can enter state,city or zip in a single input field. I am using following code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('searchservice/service')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('compstate',array('like'=>$post['input1']));
foreach ($collection as $record)
{
    $data[] = $record;
}
Mage::register('data', $data);
$this->renderLayout();
```

It is returning `compstate` result but I want that user can enter any field like zip and city also. How to use or condition here?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
echo Mage::getModel("modelalias/entityname")
->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter(
    array(
        'first_condition',
        'second_condition'
    ),
    array(
        array('eq' => 1),
        array('eq' => 0),
    )
)
->getSelect();
```

The above query will produce a SQL string like this:

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `mytablename` AS `main_table` 
WHERE (((first_condition = 1) or (second_condition = 0)))
```

You should be able to modify this to suit your need.

Comment: returning result for second condition but not for 1st one

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried? and the query it outputs using `->getSelect()`?

Comment: `$collection = Mage::getModel('searchservice/service')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
array(
'zipcode',
'compstate'
),
array(
array('eq' => $post['input1']),
array('eq' => $post['input1']),
)
)
->getSelect();`

Comment: what's the output of the `getSelect()`

Comment: enpty result i am getting

Comment: are you doing it like this: `echo Mage::getModel('searchservice/service')->getCollection(); $collection->addFieldToFilter( array( 'zipcode', 'compstate' ), array( array('eq' => $post['input1']), array('eq' => $post['input1']), ) ) ->getSelect();`

Comment: i just replaced eq to like and it is working fine now
`$collection->addFieldToFilter(
     array(
     'compstate',
     'zipcode',
     'complocality'
     ),`
` array(
     array('like' => '%'.$post['input1'].'%'),
     array('like' => '%'.$post['input1'].'%'),
     array('like' => '%'.$post['input1'].'%'),
     )
     );`
Thank You